# JQuery Tokenized Messages within a Default Required Message

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to change the default message that appears for "required" fields and discovered the "extend" option for overriding the default message for a required field.  But now I want to customize the message to include information about the control that generated the error message.  I came across the tokenized message documentation and gave that a try:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {

 required: "#{field} is required"

});

<input type="text" id="txtNamesLastName" 
class="input-medium" maxlength="50" name="nameLast" title="Last Name" />
```

When I provide a title for the input field, the error message will only show the title attribute text ("Last Name");  it will not append the additional text to the error message.  If I set `"ignoreTitle: true"` then the error message will display as `"#{field} is required"`.  What am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance!